# Merge 'recovery' and 'recovery-mode'?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

Again I've stumbled upon two tags which seem to describe the exactly same issue:

- [recovery](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recovery) (x22):

  > The Android recovery system is a bootable partition on an Android device...
- [recovery-mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recovery-mode) (x75):

  > Android's recovery mode allows ROM flashing...

The only recognizable distinction to me is the viewpoint: file system ("partition") versus boot-mode. Does that justify separate tags? I'd say: let's merge them and make the then "empty one" a synonym to the other.

Remark: We also have [data-recovery](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery) for recovering lost files. So for consistency, `recovery-mode` should IMHO be the (main) tag (also as it already holds the majority of questions), and `recovery` the synonym. I vote for a synonym as otherwise it will for sure turn up as a new tag sooner or later, referring to either the partition or the files/data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good catch. [recovery](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recovery) is now a synonym of [recovery-mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recovery-mode).